# Render HTML tags from Exception Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to render a pretty list in a Laravel Exception. The code which I have:

```
if (count($notValidatedProducts) !== 0) {
    throw new Exception('Could not create invoice. \n<br> test');
}
```

I tried the `\n` and `<br>` but non are working in the view. I can't find any documentation if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well if you are asking about how you can make a new line input `\n or <br>`

you can try this :

```
if (count($notValidatedProducts) !== 0) {
throw new Exception('Could not create invoice.'."\r\n".'test');
```

}

good luck